# What is the equivalent of Len(Dir(stringVal)) of VB.net in C#

Tags: vb.net, c#-3.0

I am new to C# and is moving some VB.net code to C#. I am stuck with the above.

What's the equivalent of `Len(Dir(stringVal))` of VB.net in C#.net 3.0 (where `stringVal` is a string variable that takes the value of a file path e.g. `C:\somedir\xyz.txt`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish ? To determine if the file exists?

in that case you can just use

```
if (File.Exists(stringVal)) { do something }
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be equivalent:

```
Path.GetFileName(stringVal).Length;
```

Breakdown:

- The `Dir()` function get the filename and extension as a string. `Path.GetFileName` does the same.
- The `Len()` function returns the length of the passed in string. The `Length` property of a string will return the length of the string.

---

If you are trying to determine if a file exist, you should simply use the static [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
if (File.Exists(stringPath))
```

Comment: +1 `Len(Dir(stringVal)) <> 0` is an old VB6 trick to determine whether a file exists.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir` in Visual Basic returns a string representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute, or the volume label of a drive.

So, if you are testing for a file you could use:

```
Path.GetFileName(stringVal).Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get length of stringVal as string you can use

```
string stringVal = @"C:\somedir\xyz.txt";
```

stringVal.Lenght - returns lenght of string.

if you want to get fileze you can use FileInfo class

```
 FileInfo fl = new FileInfo(stringVal);
long size = fl.Length;
```